# stdint header for functions exported from dll

Tags: c++, c, c++11, dllexport

I have a header for exporting some methods from a DLL which can be used both from C and C++ code:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
 {
#endif

    API_EXPORT uint32_t __cdecl GetSomeValue();

#ifdef __cplusplus
 }
#endif
```

and for uint32_t, I need to include a header, but which one is correct?

Option 1: <stdint.h>

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

#include <stdint.h>
```

Option 2:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

#include <cstdint>
```

Option 3: both.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#include <cstdint>
#else
#include <stdint.h>
#endif
```

Comment: 1 and 2 are the same, and anyway, all 3 of these are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You... just include the header.

```
#include <stdint.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
 {
#endif

    API_EXPORT uint32_t __cdecl GetSomeValue();

#ifdef __cplusplus
 }
#endif
```

You don't need to use `extern "C" {}` around built-in headers. (Sometimes you might find libraries that do need it)

Comment: the main argument presented to me is that <stdint.h> is deprecated: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header

Comment: @AndreiM well, tough s**t. You can't include cstdint in C. And stdint.h will never be removed from C++. And most people include stdint.h anyway and there are no consequences of this.

Answer (score 0):

Your option 2 generally will not work in conjunction with C compilers, so that's out.  Your option 1, or the variation presented in @user253751's answer, should be fine, but if you are concerned with protecting against buggy C, C++, or standard library implementations then I would go with this variation on your option 3:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <cstdint>
extern "C"
{
#else
#include <stdint.h>
#endif
```